# After the ending of "Preacher", are people still going to Hell or Heaven?

Tags: preacher, preacher-2016

At the end of the *Preacher* series

> Satan and his replacement - Hitler - are dead. So is God, but the Saint of All Killers is sitting on the Golden Throne.

Does it mean that dead people's souls can still go to Heaven or Hell? We know that Jesse visited (briefly) those places, but 1) he is a bit of a special case and 2)that was before the final resolution of the series.

I'm happy with answers both from the graphic novel and the series.

Comment: Does God's soul go to heaven or hell?

Answer (score 2):

We cannot be sure that Hitler is in fact dead, he died on earth but as we have seen all that means is that his soul goes to Hell, the same for Heaven, the saint sits on the throne of God, which proves there is in fact a heaven. What has probably changed are the rules around who goes to each.

As an aside I think I am right in saying that in the comics the Saint of Killers travels through Heaven and Hell are a lot more bloody with many many more angels and demons dying. In addition Hitler does not ascend to the throne of Hell after Satan is killed.

Comment: Hitler and Jesus were arguing over which souls would go to heaven and hell at their summit, but since that failed rather acrimoniously, it stands to reason that those rules did not change.

Comment: @JDoe You could say that Jesus, in the end, won with **stronger** arguments ;)